# google map zoom functionality not working

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

Currently I'm working on google-map in my project.
I am using below API version and google map displays.

```
android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2
android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2
```

**Problem:**

> when I try to zoom map on touch, google map doesn't zoom and
>   I'm unable to move the map to see another location too.

**Here's my code:**

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    //googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    mMap = googleMap;

    Log.i(TAG, "onMapReady");


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                  Toast.makeText(this,"Please enable GPS location on your phone",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return;
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "my location enabled");


    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14), 2000, null);

    buildGoogleApiClient();
    if (mMap == null) {
        return;
    }
   /* currentLatLng= new LatLng (currentLocationLatitude,currentLocationLongitude);
    Log.i(TAG,"inside onMapready --->");*/

}

 protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}
```

***XML file is included  ***
this is the xml layout file that I am using for displaying google map.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<fragment android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mega.hertz.seeky.MainActivity"/>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/vertical_page_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/horizontal_page_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/horizontal_page_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_small">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: share your XML file

Comment: hi there, I have included xml file

Answer (score 1):

Just add your fragment at bottom of your ScrollView. Because your map fragment is overlapped by ScrollView.
change your xml like:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ScrollView>

<fragment android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mega.hertz.seeky.MainActivity"/>
```

Comment: When I put fragment for google map after scroll view and compile the code and check the Ui, the placeautocimpletefragment google search for place is not appearing and only google map is appearing but I am able to zoom. I need google place search using fragment plaveautofragment

Comment: Please share your code for "PlaceAutocompleteFragment".
Also you can refer  this link: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete

Comment: thanks. my code is 
        PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(this);
        ((EditText) autocompleteFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input)).setTextSize(15.0f);

Comment: Just set your ScrollView height = "wrap_content " in your xml file. And put scroll view after fragment. Same as you uploaded xml file with your question. than you can zoom on map and also can find places.

Comment: Thank you. You mean scroll view after map fragment.appeciate it

Comment: Yes, you can zoom on Map. And also PlaceAutocompleteFragment will work.

Comment: thank you again. basic question. I have following structure in my xml file relative layout -> fragment (map) ->scrollview->linearlayout->cardview->fragment (google place). if I remove cardview and scrollview, I am not getting search google place box, I don't understand why scrollview and cardview is needed. any idea

Comment: ScrollView and CardView are not necessary. You can arrange :RelativaLayout -> Fragment(Map). and ->LinearLayout ->Fragment(Search).

Answer (score 0):

Add below function in your code;

```
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("My Location"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));      
}
```

Comment: this solution moves the map to zoom level when the map is loaded.my problem is that after the google map is loaded when I zoom it is not working and also I can't move the map basically finger touch on map is not working